# Производительность на старых мобилках

Tags: unity3d

Подскажите пожалуйста как примерно будет чувствовать себя простая 2д игра, вроде 3-в-ряд, сделанная на Unity, на старых мобилках?

Будет ли у приложения достаточное время отклика?
Будет ли комфортно пользователю?

Comment: я на старье запускал 3Д сцену с системой частиц - работало сносно. Зависит от реализации. С "3-в-ряд" нужно будет постараться что бы тормозило. Хотя зачем под старые мобилки что-то производить...

Comment: Если в ответ добавите, отмечу как правильный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я на старье запускал 3Д сцену с системой частиц - работало сносно. Зависит от реализации. С "3-в-ряд" нужно будет постараться что бы тормозило.

Хотя зачем под старые мобилки что-то производить.
Вот процент пользователей по версии: https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html
Платежеспособность юзеров с устаревшим гаджетами стремится к нулю.  А большинство из них даже не сможет скачать игру. Тот телефон на котором я запускал имел встроенной памяти меньше 90 MB.